# Show Message in text box when program ends successfuly or not

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I have the below code that when it runs updates 14 tables, wondering how can I show a msg using the text boxes in the template below showing whether the subs end successfully or not.

```
[Private Sub Command0_Click()

   'Sub 1
    A_Forecast
    
    'Text box showing the msg OK or failed
    A_ForecastTxt "OK" or "Not"

   'Sub 2
    B_Forecast
    
    'Text box showing the msg OK or failed
    B_ForecastTxt "OK" or "Not"

   
End Sub][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the subs into *functions* as these can return a value:

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim Success As Boolean

    ' Function 1
    Success = A_Forecast
    
    ' Text box showing the msg OK or failed
    MsgBox IIf(Success, "OK", "Failed")

    ' Function 2
    Success = B_Forecast
    
    ' Text box showing the msg OK or failed
    MsgBox IIf(Success, "OK", "Failed")
   
End Sub
```

Example:

```vb
Public Function A_Forecast() As Currency

    Dim Result As Currency
    Dim Something As Boolean

    ' Your code:
    Something = True ' or False

    If Something = True Then
        Result = 100
    Else
        Result = 200
    End If

    A_Forecast = Result

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, thats is a good idea. However not sure how can I convert the subs into functions. Have tried your code but keep getting the Error msg: Expected Function or variable.

Comment: I've added a basic example.